# RDP / MSTSC resizing remote desktop resolution down

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution

So i have both at work and at home Win 10 Pro at 1903 and 2560x1440 displays, both on scale 100%. But when i connect from home to work PC (always in fullscreen mode) all my windows with bigger window than 1920x1080 on the remote work PC are resized down to 1920x1080. Basicaly it seems like RDP is on connection set for max resolution 1920x1080 and all my windows are resized and put to top-left corner area of that size. But after connection i'm in 2560x1440 desktop and i can move them or resize them up to that resolution. Up until Win 10 1903 i had to make this resize back only for the first time i've connected to remote PC and every other reconnection was fine, no resized windows or anything, until i've logged on the PC physically, the next remote connection was again resized. After 1903 update every connection to remote PC resizes the windows down to 1920x1080. So it's even worse than before...

**Here are my conection settings:**

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:2560
desktopheight:i:1440
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:##########
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:0
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
drivestoredirect:s:*
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
smart sizing:i:1
```

I've tried to mess with

> winposstr

and

> smart sizing

parameters but to no avail...

I've also tried the MS's UWP RPD Client from Windows Store and mRemoteNG and the results are the same. My questions is what to set on remote or local PC to make this work without windows resizing.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution yet? I'm having the same issue and going crazy trying all the slutions that do not work...

Comment: Unfortuanately no...

Comment: So no answer... but workaround... if you use PowerToys with FancyZones on remote PC to manage window sizes and positions, then after connection, windows will still downsize, but FancyZones will snap them back, either automatically or manually. Anyway it's much easier to work around the problem now.